# Kotlin how to launch app when phone wakes up

Tags: android, kotlin

I just googled but can't find really working solution for that problem. I want to make a little app. When the app is not working, user do off and on the phone, i want to launch my app. But i mean sleep (close the screen few seconds etc.) not actually turn off the phone. How can i detect it and launch my app?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) witch detects when the screens turns on.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // your code here


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, not working for me, you sure it's still okay?